# Replace string in raw data response is not working

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP CURL i'm calling one URL and i'm getting some response from one page,Now I need to replace one string from that response but it's not working,please check my code below.

```
$url = "My URL";
$url1 = $url1 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$raw_data1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$raw = str_replace('@', 'Test', $raw_data1);
echo $raw;
```

Comment: Could you post the content of `$raw_data1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to replace special character,My suggestion is you should try to use `preg_replace()` instead of `str_replace()`

Try the below example:

```
$url = "My URL";
$url1 = $url1 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$raw_data1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$raw = preg_replace("([@]+)", "Test", $raw_data1);
echo $raw;
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace a pattern of string always use `preg_replace()` and in your case the response is coming from other source so better way to replace the string is to find define a pattern and replace Using `preg_replace()`

This is what you need `preg_replace("([@]+)", "test", $raw_data1);`